# $f(x,y)=\displaystyle\int_{x^2+y^2}^{x^2+y^2+1} g(t) dt $ is two times continuously differentiable, calculate its gradient and find local extrema

Tags: integration, differential-topology

I am preparing for my exam by practicing some tasks. I need someone to check, if I did everything correct:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function with g'(t)>0 for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $$f(x,y)=\int_{x^2+y^2}^{x^2+y^2+1} g(t)dt$$

> a) Show that f is two times continuously differentiable and calculate its gradient

> b) Determine all local extrema and classificate them.

Well I am pretty unsure how to solve this, but this is what I have so far:

> a) Show that f is two times continuously differentiable and calculate its gradient

Since $g$ is continuous we could write $$f(x,y)=G(x^2+y^2+1)-G(x^2+y^2)$$ with G being an antiderivative of g.

And since G is differentiable and  $(x^2+y^2(+1))$ as well, $f$ is differentiable. We would then have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x(g(x^2+y^2+1)- g(x^2+y^2))$$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y(g(x^2+y^2+1)- g(x^2+y^2))$$.

And since g is continuous and $2x$ and $2y$ are continuous, both partial derivatives are continuous and thus the whole derivative is continuous.

Since we know that g is differentiable, $(x^2+y^2+1)$ and $2x$/$2y$ as well, we know that $f'(x,y)$ is differentiable as well.

We then would get
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=2(g(x^2+y^2+1)-g(x^2+y^2)) + 4x^2(g'(x^2+y^2+1)-g'(x^2+y^2))$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=2(g(x^2+y^2+1)-g(x^2+y^2)) + 4y^2(g'(x^2+y^2+1)-g'(x^2+y^2))$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}= 4xy(g'(x^2+y^2+1)-g'(x^2+y^2))$$

Since g is continuously differentiable, g' is continuous and the combination of continuous parts is continuous as well. Thats why f''(x,y) is continuous too.

Thats why we can say: f is two times continuous differentiable.
Also $$grad(f)=(2x(g(x^2+y^2+1)- g(x^2+y^2)); 2y(g(x^2+y^2+1)- g(x^2+y^2)))^T$$

Is that correct? I really doubt it though because it seems too easy if thats correct.

> b) Determine all local extrema and classificate them

Well we first look for critical points right? A point $x_0$ is critical, if f is differentiable at $x_0$ with $$grad f(x_0)=0$$

So when is $grad f=0$? Well since $g'>0$, which means that $g$ is strictly increasing and  $x^2+y^2+1$ is bigger than $x^2+y^2$ $\implies$ $g(x^2+y^2+1)-g(x^2+y^2)>0$. This means $grad f=0$ only if $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

We then use hurwitz theorem. We have $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0)=2(g(y^2+1)-g(y^2))>0$$. Also we have $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(0)-\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}(0)=2(g(y^2+1)-g(y^2)+g(x^2+1)-g(x^2))>0$$ which means that f has a strict local minima in $(0,0)$.

Is that correct? I am just asking because it seems to be a too easy task if I compare it with the difficult tasks my teacher is usually giving us.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: It looks ok... well, when computing the $2\times 2$ matrix $f''(0,0)$, there should survive no $x,y$ in the formula, just replace every $x,y$ when evaluating in $(0,0)$ by the zero value...

Comment: @dan_fulea Ah I see. You mean that I would have 2(g(1)-g(0))>0 and 2(g(1)-g(0)+g(1)-g(0))>0 right?

Answer (score 2):

We can do the polar change of variable: $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. So the integral simplifies to:
$$f(r)=\int_{r^2}^{r^2+1}g(t)\;dt$$
with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

The gradient is simple to compute, as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}r=\cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}r=\sin(\theta)$.
$$\nabla f(r)=2r\left(g(r^2+1)-g(r^2)\right)\left(\cos(\theta)\hat x+\sin(\theta)\hat y\right)$$

This is null at $r=0$, which means that there is a local extrema at $x=y=0$. As $g'(t)$ is positive, then $g(t+1)>g(t)$ for all $t\ge0$ so the gradient will never change sign and will always point outwards from the origin. So we have a global minimum at $x=y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is my solution for a) and b) correct. I thought maybe its the wrong way to show that f is two times continuously differentiable. And is (0,0) the only critical point/local extrema?

Comment: I think that there could be other critical points, if $g(t+1)=g(t)$ for example. The gradient would be null for the whole circle of radius $\sqrt t$ in this case.

Comment: I don't think that we can decide if the extremum is a maximum or a minimum. You can see this in the equation you provided, if you exchange $g(t)$ with $-g(t)$ then you reverse the full equation.

Comment: But g(t+1) can't be the same as g(t) since g'>0 which means that g is strictly increasing. So g(t+1)>g(t). We can decide that its a local minima, because of hurwitz theorem.

Comment: Ah I missed that $g'(t)$ is positive, then yes, you are correct. I will amend the answer.

Comment: So are my solutions for a) and b) correct and complete?

Comment: I think so, however the change of coordinate to polar make the proof much simpler!